# how to get some text when using svg tags

Tags: html, svg

How can i get some text between svg tags?

I am using this piece of code and i want some text inside the blue area:

```
<div class="container2">
Here should be some text
<svg viewBox="1 1 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="yMinYMin meet">
<path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,1 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke:  none; fill:#05aed9;"></path>
</svg>
```

And here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucLkwh65/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a HTML tag within the container then you can set the positioning to absolute and display the text:

```
<div class="container2">
<h1 class="innertext">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
</h1>
<svg viewBox="1 1 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="yMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,1 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#05aed9;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Then add the CSS:

```
.innertext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

This will create the following effect:

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
svg.one {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.innertext {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
body {
   margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg class="one" viewBox="0 0 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,0 500,100 L500,00 L0,0 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#1e90ff;"></path>
  </svg>
  
</div>

<div class="container2">
<h1 class="innertext">
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit
</h1>
<svg viewBox="1 1 500 500" preserveAspectRatio="yMinYMin meet">
    <path d="M0,100 C150,200 350,1 500,100 L500,00 L0,1 Z" style="stroke: none; fill:#05aed9;"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the solution